# EclipseLink in Jersey Test Framework blocking test

Tags: java, moxy, jersey-test-framework, scim2

I'm trying to write some integration tests for a SCIM client implementation and EclipseLink has me blocked.

The SCIM User schema includes a nested Email object.  Email has a field called 'type'.  This is part of the standard and is not a discriminator field.  However, EclipseLink apparently has decided that any field named 'type' is a discriminator and explodes trying to deserialize my requests.

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Server-side request processing failed with an error.
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryConnector$InMemoryResponseWriter.failure(InMemoryConnector.java:167)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:509)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
at org.glassfish.jersey.test.inmemory.InMemoryConnector.apply(InMemoryConnector.java:275)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at edu.psu.swe.scim.client.rest.BaseScimClient$InternalScimClient.update(BaseScimClient.java:291)
at edu.psu.swe.scim.client.rest.BaseScimClient.update(BaseScimClient.java:122)
at edu.psu.swe.scim.client.rest.BaseScimClient.update(BaseScimClient.java:118)
[...]
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-43] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing class for indicator field value [] of type [class java.lang.String].
Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(edu.psu.swe.scim.spec.resources.Email --> [])
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingClassForIndicatorFieldValue(DescriptorException.java:940)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.QNameInheritancePolicy.classFromRow(QNameInheritancePolicy.java:278)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.classFromRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:182)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.classFromRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:1)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLRelationshipMappingNodeValue.processChild(XMLRelationshipMappingNodeValue.java:63)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.startElement(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:184)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl.startElement(UnmarshalRecordImpl.java:860)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parsePair(JsonStructureReader.java:379)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parseRoot(JsonStructureReader.java:191)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:140)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:978)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:425)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:375)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:708)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:643)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:339)
at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:660)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:94)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
```

I'm not sure how to tell EclipseLink that this third-party entity is not using inheritance, it just has a field named 'type'.

I'm using the PennState [SCIMple Identity](https://github.com/PennState/SCIMple-Identity) client library.

Comment: Note that I'm not using EclipseLink directly.  It's being used by the Jersey Test Framework InMemoryTestContainer.

Comment: Try using Jackson instead of MOXy

Comment: There's not really any clear instructions on how to do that with the Test Framework.  I tried adding JacksonFeature in the `protected Application configure()` override, but that doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: Figured it out.  I had followed the client instructions too closely and didn't realize I had imported MOXy.  Just removing that and the client grabs Jackson automatically.